# CSS style if showing up in IE

Tags: css

I am building a separate stylesheet for IE.  I am using this code between

```
<head> 

<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iestyle.css" /> 
![endif]-->


</head>
```

The problem is, this part is being printed to the screen on the page in IE:

```
  ![endif]-->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to start the closing tag. use this

```
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: no problems. You're not alone i make mistakes like these all the time.